# How to use VS Code - Python Shell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-idle

So I am relatively new to programming and used to use Python's own `"IDLE"`. After I run a `".py"` file with `IDLE`, I am used to getting a python shell or a command window, I don't really know the terminological name for it, where I could play around with the objects inside the script.

For example, if I had a `list A=[1,2,3]` inside the program, after I run it I get a command console that says `">>"` and I can say `">>A"` which gives me `"[1,2,3]"` and I can add elements to `A` etc.

Now, I want to start using `VS Code` but I can't seem to find that particular thing. I have a terminal where I can run python code if I give the command "python" first, but It doesn't seem to effect anything inside the script.

I want to use that to see if some objects are working fine and to check their types etc. I add more lines to code after I try from there first, if that makes sense.

Sorry for really bad terminology, I really don't know the names but I can try even more if it's not clear.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#:%7E:text=To%20open%20the%20terminal%3A,View%3A%20Toggle%20Integrated%20Terminal%20command.) of VS Code?

Here are some ways to open the terminal:

- Use the ⌃` keyboard shortcut with the backtick character.
- Use the View > Terminal menu command.
- From the Command Palette (⇧⌘P), use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command.

In the window that shows up, enter `python` and you'll get the Python shell you're looking for.

Comment: After I write python on the terminal, I can write python code and it runs it but it doesn't see the already defined things on the script and says NameError: name 'A' is not defined for example.

Comment: You'll need to copy-paste the contents of the script into the Python shell first :)
The Python shell starts afresh and does not know what's in your `.py` file

Comment: Ahaha is there no way for it to work like I want it? Because IDLE has it built in, after the .py file runs the shell can interpret the stuff inside the file... :( sad.

Comment: When you run a python file with python.exe on a command line, it normally runs and exits.  If you add the '-i' (interactive) option, `python -i xyz.py`, python switches to interactive mode and prints '>>>' instead of exiting.  IDLE acts the same way when one runs code from an IDLE editor.  I have not used VS Code but perhaps knowing that you are looking for '-i' or an imitation thereof will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the integrated terminal inside vs code and make sure that python and pip are properly configured. Type `python` in the command line and make sure the terminal points to the same folder where your program file is located.

Comment: Ok so the program I wrote has A=[1,2,3] but after I tried this, it says: NameError: name 'A' is not defined

Comment: Xia, you need to ensure you have copy-pasted the code into the terminal or at least declared the objects before trying to access them. 
For example: run `A = [2, 3, 4]` before looking for what's inside A.